# strtof undefined; assuming extern returning int

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

may be this is a really stupid question but I don't get it ... for conversion from an ASCII-representation to related number I use strtof() in Visual Studio 2012. According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn320175.aspx (and accordng to Linux manpages where it compiles fine with gcc) stdlib.h needs to be included.

Now my problem: I already *have* an `#include <stdlib.h>` in my file but still get this compile error!

Any idea what could be missing?

Thanks!

Edit: code example

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static char *get_xyz(char *c,float *x,float *y,float *z)
{
   c++;

   if ((*c=='X') || (*c == 'A') || (*c=='x') || (*c=='a'))
   {
      c++;
      if (*c) *x=strtof(c,NULL);
   }

   if ((*c=='Y') || (*c=='B') || (*c=='y') || (*c=='b'))
   {
      c++;
      if (*c) *y=strtof(c,NULL);
   }

   if (z)
   {
      if ((*c=='Z') || (*c=='C') || (*c=='z') || (*c=='c'))
      {
         c++;
         if (*c) *z=strtof(c,NULL);
      }
   }

   return c;
}
```

Comment: can you show a MCVE? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Post the error and code.

Comment: It corresponds to Visual Studio 2013 or later. Use `strtod` instead of `strtof`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: thanks, this was the solution!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Visual Studio does not conform to the C standard. `strtof` was introduced in the C language in the year 1999, which was just 13 years before the release of VS2012. Microsoft had not yet updated their compiler to these changes.

I think they have now finally introduced partial support for this (previous) C language standard with the VS2015 version. I don't think they support the current C standard from 2011 at all.

Your best bet is to use a standard compliant C compiler instead.